# When https is used, does the web server request resources using SSL?

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, https

I have a website on Server A which users access via SSL (i.e. through an https URL). In order to respond to certain requests, Server A must make its own web requests to Server B.

Would A's requests to B be encrypted without a certificate being installed on B?

Comment: this question should ask on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends how A sends its requests to B. If A uses SSL/TLS to send the requests, they are encrypted, otherwise they are not. This is totally independent of whether or not A serves its own pages via HTTPS.

Comment: So basically the two requests (i.e. from user to Server A and from Server A to Server B) are totally independent wrt SSL?

Comment: @David: Yes, of course. Why and how do you expect them to be linked? They come from different computers, and connect to different computers, after all.

Comment: Awesome, that's all I wanted to know.